# gparted installed on OpenSuse shows all file system types as greyed out except for hfs

Tags: opensuse, gparted

I have had this problem before and fixed it, but I don't recall how I did it and I did not record it (sadness :( )

I have all the requisite commands installed on OpenSuse to support gparted's efforts in creating any of the supported file systems. I recall that the problem was that gparted could not find the commands, in any event all the file systems are greyed out in the context menu except for the legacy hfs partition which only supports < 2gb. Even extfs2-extfs4 are greyed out.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You should migrate this question to superuser.

Answer (score 1):

its probably a two-fold issue.

1. Make sure you have the correct kernel modules for the filesystems
2. Make sure you have the correct userland tools for the filesystems installed.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
cd /usr/sbin
sudo bash    
./gparted
```

anybetter?

if not search for ntfsprogs at http://software.opensuse.org/search and install it and retry above steps.

Answer (score 0):

Is gparted launched with root privileges (using sudo or equivalent) ?

Comment: Yes - I am running gparted with root privs through gnomesu.